# Spring Boot - Spring Security - InvalidBearerTokenException Error Handling

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

Similar to this question but it got no answers: [Spring Security: Handle InvalidBearerTokenException in @ExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66885068/spring-security-handle-invalidbearertokenexception-in-exceptionhandler)

I have similar code and I'm trying to catch `org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.InvalidBearerTokenException` when a user has supplied invalid/expired/bad `JWT` format.

```
    @Component
    public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
        private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;
    
        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                             AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
    
            resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, e);
        }
    }
```

```
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {
        @Autowired
        private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
        @Autowired
        private CustomAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            // other config here
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    
            http.exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
        }
    }
```

I've also implemented the `@ExceptionHandler` of `AuthenticationException` for custom response.

```
        @ExceptionHandler({AuthenticationException.class})
        protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleAuthException(AuthenticationException ex, WebRequest req)
        {
            CustomResponse response = ...
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, ...);
        }
```

`InvalidBearerTokenException` is a subclass of `AuthenticationException`.
Any idea why this `AuthenticationEntryPoint` code is not catching it? I've also tried adding logging inside the `commence` method but it's not being called when `InvalidBearerTokenException` is thrown, but other `AuthenticationException` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify this `AuthenticationEntryPoint` inside the `OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer`, like so:

```java
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            // other config here
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().and()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
        }
```

When you set it, the Configurer will change the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` that is used inside the `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter`, see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/386e8a86a1c9634177154ad946286b1f62bc62f1/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/server/resource/OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java#L265).

Comment: This is working! Thank you! Just a minor edit, need to add `and()` before the authenticationEntryPoint (and/or accessDeniedHandler)

Comment: After 2 days, I've finally resolved this! Thank you!